# How to Clear Extension Attributes

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have an application which can be used to either set or clear some AD attribute `extensionAttribute2`.

Everything appears to work fine, but after updating my ode to use the `Property.Clear()` method when clearing out the attribute, I ran into some problems.

After calling `ActiveDirectory.ClearProperty("user.name", "extensionAttribute2")`, that property is cleared, but when I try setting it with `ActiveDirectory.GetProperty("user.name", "extensionAttribute2", "123456789")` I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

And I can see that the `extensionAttribute2` has not been loaded in the `DirectoryEntry` object for the user.

If I change the code in `ClearProperty` to call `user.Properties[property].Value = " ";` then it appears to work fine (i.e. the property still exists when querying the user again), however I feel that using `Clear()`.

Is this normal behaviour for AD? I got the impression that calling `Clear` just clears the value rather than actually destroying the property, or is this a feature of `extensionAttribute`s? I would like to use `Clear` as it looks clearner - does this seem reasonable or is sticking with `user.Properties[property].Value = " ";` really the best option?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
private static DirectoryEntry GetUser(string friendlyName)
{
    var userEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=DOMAIN,dc=co,dc=uk");
    var mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(userEntry)
    { Filter = $"(cn={friendlyName})" };

    mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute2");
    mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

    var userSearchResult = mySearcher.FindOne();
    var distinguishedName = userSearchResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
    var userDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{distinguishedName}");

    return userDirectoryEntry;
}

public static string GetProperty(string friendlyname, string property)
{
    var user = GetUser(friendlyname);
    return user.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
}
public static void SetProperty(string friendlyName, string property, string value)
{
    var user = GetUser(friendlyName);
    user.Properties[property].Value = value;
    user.CommitChanges();
}

public static void ClearProperty(string friendlyName, string property)
{
    var user = GetUser(friendlyName);
    user.Properties[property].Clear();
    user.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm still not sure why the code is behaving like this, I managed to overcome this issue with the following:

```
public static string GetProperty(string friendlyname, string property)
{
    var user = GetUser(friendlyname);
    try
    {
        return user.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        throw "No property found";
    }
}
```

This way I can handle whatever exception I throw from here and use this to indicate that the user's extension property is empty.